# How can I use Google docs OCR api in Android?

Tags: java, android, ocr, google-docs-api

I want to use Google Docs API for OCR in my Android application. But I could not find any useful tutorial/code example. Any link/example/tutorial to upload image and getting text?

Answer (score 0):

There is a live demo here http://googlecodesamples.com/docs/php/ocr.php

I am not sure if that will help you much, but if you do find anything, please let me know.
I'm attempting to do something similar.

Comment: i have looked this one, but now i gave up. tried a new method without using google docs api. if you says about ocr in android i did it with [tesseract](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/).